# Why doesn't len(None) return 0?

Tags: python, nonetype

`None` in Python is an object.

```
>>> isinstance(None, object)
True
```

And as such it can employ functions like __str__()

```
>>> str(None)
'None'
```

But why doesn't it do the same for __len__()?

```
>>> len(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    len(None)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

It seems like it would be Pythonic the same way that `if list` is acceptable even if the variable is `None` and not just an empty list.

Are there cases that would make the use of `len(None)` more of a problem?

Comment: Because `None` doesn't have a `__len__`; it isn't [`Sized`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sized).

Comment: @jonrsharpe But it could just have an added function that returns 0 no matter what.

Comment: it could but it would not make much sense. Why would an object have a length unless it is a collection of objects?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I'm not sure what *level* you're asking this question at - *why doesn't `len(None)` currently work*, or *why shouldn't `len(None)` be implemented*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was wondering why it shouldn't be implemented, just because it comes up often as an error when a function returns None instead of a list. Which could be avoided with this being added but I thought there might be a distinction I was missing.

Comment: If you have a situation where you could get `None` or a `list`, you should be testing `if what_i_think_is_a_list is not None:` before treating it as a list. All built-in types have truthiness, but there are plenty of operations that make no sense on `None` (you can't iterate over it, either). Implementing `len` for `None` would just hide errors that should be caught.

Comment: `None` doesn't have a length for the same reason integers and floats don't have a length. *It is not a collection*. It cannot become longer or shorter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mention that you want this:

> because it comes up often as an error when a function returns `None` instead of a list

Presumably, you have code like:

```
list_probably = some_function()
for index in range(len(list_probably)):
    ...
```

and are getting:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Note the following:

- `len` is for determining the length of *collections* (e.g. a `list`, `dict` or `str` - these are [`Sized`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sized) objects). It's *not* for converting arbitrary objects to integers - it also isn't implemented for `int` or `bool`, for example;
- If `None` is a possibility, you should be explicitly testing `if list_probably is not None`. Using e.g. `if list_probably` would treat `None` and the empty list `[]` the same, which is probably not the correct behaviour; and
- There is usually a better way to deal with lists that `range(len(...))`- e.g. `for item in list_probably`, using `zip`, etc.

Implementing `len` for `None` would just **hide errors** where `None` is being treated, incorrectly, like some other object - per [the Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (`import this`):

> Errors should never pass silently.

Similarly `for item in None` would fail, but that doesn't mean that implementing `None.__iter__` is a good idea! Errors are a good thing - they help you find the problems in your programs quickly.

Answer (score 17):

`len` only makes sense for collections of objects - None is not a collection.

Comment: Does it make inherently less sense to say it could always return 0 than the truthiness (or, falsiness) of `None`?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Yes, it makes less sense. Ask yourself, is the length of the color red 0?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan yes! An integer doesn't have a length either, but has truthiness - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing. Also note that you should generally test `None` by *identity* rather than *truthiness*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That in particular is a good point. I guess I was thinking about len() as just returning an int value representing the variable instead of explicitly as a count of a collection. (also I was referring to testing a list with truthiness and it handling the case when you have None instead of a list)

Answer (score 7):

If you have an item that might return `None` you can use `len(None or '')` and it will `return 0` or the length of the first item if it is `not None`.