# Why is pandas.apply() executing on null elements?

Tags: python, pandas

Supposedly, the pandas.apply() function does not apply to null elements. However, this is not occuring in the following code. Why is this happening?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series([[1,2],[2,3,4,5],None])
df
0          [1, 2]
1    [2, 3, 4, 5]
2            None
dtype: object
df.apply(lambda x: len(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", l
ine 2169, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1059, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\li
b.c:62578)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: What do you mean it "supposedly does not apply to null elements"?

Comment: Maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30257332/2901002

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: len(x) if x is not None else None)`

Comment: @BrenBarn, the documentation says that it does not act on null elements.

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley: could you be more specific about where it says that?  The docs might need to be clarified if they're misleading.  (PS: calling a Series `df` is a little confusing, because that's the standard short name for a DataFrame.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None and nan are semantically equivalent. There is no point in replacing None with numpy.nan.  `apply` will still apply the function to NaN elements.

```
df[2] = numpy.nan
df.apply(lambda x: print(x))

Output: [1, 2]
        [2, 3, 4, 5]
        nan
```

You have to check for a missing value in your function you want to apply or use `pandas.dropna` and apply the function to the result:

```
df.dropna().apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

Alternatively, use `pandas.notnull()` which returns a series of booleans:

```
df[df.notnull()].apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

Please also read: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

And specifically, this:

> Warning:
>
> One has to be mindful that in python (and numpy), the nan's don’t
>   compare equal, but None's do. Note that Pandas/numpy uses the fact
>   that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.

Comment: So just curious, why does the following code work then:

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,None])
>>> a.apply(lambda x: x+1)
0     2
1     3
2     4
3     5
4   NaN
dtype: float64

Comment: Why wouldn't it? None + 1 = NaN according to numpy because None is treated as NaN (as the warning clearly states above).

Answer (score 3):

Even more important as a follow up to kliron's answer.  If you want to reassign the output to a new column, it's important to note that your index's will no longer match up. To do so:

`df.loc[df.notnull(), 'new_col'] = df[df.notnull()].apply(lambda x: print(x))`